# Why does it give the same output for every value?

Tags: c++

```
int main (void)
{
    char n;
    label0:
    cout<<"Please enter a character value(C/S)\n";
    cin>>n;
    n = toupper(n);
    if ( n!= 'C' || n!= 'S' )
    {
        cout<<"Please enter proper value\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        goto label0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"You entered"<<n<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;  
}
```

In this code, even when I enter `c C s S` , it gives the same output as Please enter the proper value. Why is it not comparing?

Comment: You don't need `goto` here... Avoiding `goto` when it doesn't make code simpler is IMO good habit.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( n!= 'C' || n!= 'S' )
```

This is `true` for every `n` in the world. You probably meant to use `&&`.

Think about it:

- if `n == 'C'`, then the condition is satisfied since `n != 'S'`,
- if `n == 'S'`, then the condition is satisfied since `n != 'C'`,
- if `n == 'X'`, then the condition is satisfied since `n != 'C'`,
- ...

Read more about [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: But then how do I check if the input given is something else apart from `C` or `c` or `s` or `S`. ?

Comment: @user3776323 you use `&&` instead of `||`. You want to check if the character is not `C` **and** it is not `S`.

Comment: BTW u should avoid the goto statement where ever possible as its use can lead into sphagetthi code

Comment: uhm what is point for this specific question about short circuit evaluation ? even if full evaluation would occur the premises is wrong, so problem is not about short circuit evaluation. In fact it could be about short circuit evaluation if operator was XOR.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you are having trouble by understanding the way in that logical operators are used.

The condition `n != 'C'` is equivalent to `!(n == 'C')`.
Thus, the `if()` condition in your code can be rewritten in this way:

```
  if ( !(n == 'C') || !(n == 'S') )
```

However, the condition you need in your code is another one:

```
  if ( ! (n == 'C' || n == 'S') )
```

I suggest to do the job in reverse order:

```
if ( n== 'C' || n== 'S' )
{
    cout<<"You entered"<<n<<"\n";
}
else
{
    cout<<"Please enter proper value\n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    goto label0;
}
```

In this way, if the entered character is c C s S, then the character is correct, and in any other case, a new character must be entered.

On the other hand, the `goto` statements must be used only in excepcional cases, when the flow of the program becomes very intrincated, and one really need "to jump out of the mess".

However, your program is very simple, and can be achieved with normal loop control sentences, such as `do {} while()`:

```
int main (void)
{
    char n;
    do {
        cout<<"Please enter a (proper) character value(C/S)\n";
        cin>>n;
        n = toupper(n);

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();

    } while ( ! (n == 'C' || n == 'S') );

    cout<<"You entered"<<n<<"\n";

    return 0;  
}
```

Now, the user is enforced to enter one of the desired characters: c C s S, until the entered character is correct.